# BeautifulSoup: extract text from HTML lists exclusively marked with bullet points

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text within a **bulleted** list from a [Wikipedia article](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducado_de_Medinaceli) by using BeautifulSoup.

I know that the elements in a list are represented via the **<li>** tag in HTML, but this is apparently irrespective of the type of marker used before each element in the list (a number, a roman number, a letter or a bullet point).

So far, I have tried this code:

```
# Get URL content
page = requests.get("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duque_de_Medinaceli")

# Scrape webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
list_items = soup.find_all('li')
for list_item in list_items:
    print(list_item.text)
```

However, all list elements being contained within <li> tag are extracted no matter the marker they have (number, bullet point, etc.), but **I want the list item if and only if it has a bullet point as a marker.**

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The *marker* is styled using CSS and `beautifulsoup` doesn't read/parse CSS - so it doesn't know which `<li>` tags have marker or not.

To extract the correct tags you want you can use for example CSS selector:

```py
list_items = soup.select('.mw-parser-output > ul > li')
for list_item in list_items:
    print(list_item.text)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Alfonso X de Castilla, «el Sabio» (Toledo, 23 de noviembre de 1221-Sevilla, 4 de abril de 1284) Casó con Violante de Aragón, hija de Jaime I de Aragón.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fernando de la Cerda (Valladolid, 23 de octubre de 1255-Ciudad Real, 25 de julio de 1275), Infante de Castilla, fue el hijo primogénito del rey Alfonso X de Castilla y heredero al trono castellano hasta su fallecimiento en el año 1275. Contrajo matrimonio en Burgos el 30 de noviembre de 1269 con Blanca de Francia,[2]​ hija del rey Luis IX de Francia, y de Margarita de Provenza.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alfonso de la Cerda «el Desheredado» (Valladolid, 1270-Piedrahíta, 1333), al fallecer su padre le arrebató sus derechos a la corona de Castilla y León su tío Sancho IV de Castilla. Casó con Mahalda de Brienne-Eu.[3]​
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Luis de la Cerda (Francia, 1291-Lamotte du Rhône, 5 de julio de 1348), fue el primer conde de Talmont en 1338 y de Clermont, almirante de Francia (1340–1341), príncipe soberano de las Islas Afortunadas (Islas Canarias). Casó en primeras nupcias en Sevilla en 1306 con Leonor Pérez de Guzmán y Coronel, señora de Huelva y del Puerto de Santa María, hija de Alonso Pérez de Guzmán «el Bueno», y de María Alfonso Coronel.[2]​ Contrajo un segundo matrimonio en 1346, en Francia, con Giote D'Uzes, hija de Roberto I, vizconde de Uzes, y de Guiote de Posquières.[2]​
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```